# How to add two rows in excel by using their names?

Tags: excel, sum

I am trying to calculate the amount of calories, fat, protein, ... in a recipe of food. As you see in the picture, I named the row containing avocado and salmon values as "Avocado" and "Salmon". I want to use the names "Avocado" and "Salmon" to add the value of these two rows in a new row that is preferentially is named "Avodaco + Salmon", however, if the name of the new row is something as "A4" that is fine too. I would also like to multiply the values of the "Avocado" row by 0.7 (for 70 gram of Avocado) before adding the rows "Avocado" and "Salmon".
Can somebody explain how I can do it? I have no experience with excel.

[image]

**Edit**

I would be good if I could add the values of "Avocado" and "Salmon" that are, for example" in sheet named as "Fat" in another sheet named as "Recipe".

[image]

Comment: you can look into SUMIF and SUMIFS as a start https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Answer (score 0):

Do column B and then copy B4 (Ctrl-C) and highlight the rest of row 4 (drag the cursor across) and paste (Ctrl-V). The cell references will adjust themselves.

B4 calculates your first result: =B2*0.7+B3 
You can put any label you want in A4

Your "Recipe" sheet can reference any cell in "Fat" thus:
=Fat!B4

Comment: I don't get the first part "Do column B". Then "Copy B4", but it is empty.

Comment: Follow the direction in paragraph 2. Put =B2*0.7+B3 into B4 (Don't miss the = ) This means  "=" says it's a formula, then multiply the contents of B2 by the 0.7 that you specified, and then add the contents of B3. I don't think you can use your labels to do the calculation.